# How can we plot data from a multi-index dataframe in a heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I am pivoting a dataframe like this.

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df_build, values='Expense', index=['Name'], columns=['Comments', 'Venue'], aggfunc=np.sum)
pvt = pvt.fillna(0)
pvt.columns
```

Now, I have a dataframe with these columns.

```
MultiIndex([(       'Build',        'Arena'),
            (       'Build',      'Stadium'),
            (       'Add',          'Arena'),
            (       'New',        'Stadium'),
            (       'Replace',      'Arena')],
           names=['Comments', 'Venue'])
```

I am trying to plot this data as a heatmap. I'd prefer to use Plotly, but Seaborn is fine too. I thought the code below would work, but it did not.

```
df_fin = pvt.reset_index().pivot(columns='Comments', index='Venue', values='Expense')
ax = sns.heatmap(df_fin)
ax.plot()
```

Maybe there is some kind of melt that needs to occur. Not sure. How can I plot this data as a heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have simulated what I believe is the structure of your pivoted data frame
- core is to reshape this dataframe to make it compatible with https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/#heatmap-with-plotlyexpress-and-pximshow

  - `stack()` y-axis of heatmap
  - ensure index is only one level (`droplevel()`)
  - generate figure

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# build df that matches pivoted df
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [
            ["Build", "Build", "Add", "New", "Replace"],
            ["Arena", "Stadium", "Arena", "Stadium", "Arena"],
        ],
        names=["Comments", "Venue"],
    ),
    data = np.random.randint(1,5,5)
).T

# now restructure it for plotly
dfp = df.stack("Venue").droplevel(0,0)

# finally a simple plotly figure...
px.imshow(dfp.values, x=dfp.columns, y=dfp.index)
```

[image]